# How does MariaDB handle joins on ENUMs?

Tags: mysql, join, mariadb, enum

I'm just wondering because MySQL `ENUM`s are essentially tied to the table, how do they handle `JOIN`s if two tables have the same `ENUM`? Are they join based on the `ENUM` value's or the string-key (input)?

For the follow-up see also, [*How does MariaDB handle ENUM types used in FOREIGN KEY constraints?*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207540/how-does-mariadb-handle-enum-types-used-in-foreign-key-constraints)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two tables can't have the same `ENUM`s. MySQL assumes all `ENUM` keys are globally unique..

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( a ENUM ('A', 'B', 'C'), x int );
CREATE TABLE bar ( a ENUM ('A', 'C', 'D'), y int );
INSERT INTO foo ( a, x ) VALUES ('A',1), ('B',2), ('C',3);
INSERT INTO bar ( a, y ) VALUES ('A',4), ('C',5), ('D',6);

SELECT * FROM foo JOIN bar USING(a);
+------+------+------+
| a    | x    | y    |
+------+------+------+
| A    |    1 |    4 |
| C    |    3 |    5 |
+------+------+------+
```

So in this context, the value of the `ENUM` is the string value of the key. PostgreSQL will return the same result, but because it has actual `ENUM` types the comparisons in the join are `interger` and it doesn't have to resolve the `ENUM` to a string,

```
CREATE TYPE myType AS ENUM ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
CREATE TABLE foo ( a myType, x int );
CREATE TABLE bar ( a myType, y int );
INSERT INTO foo ( a, x ) VALUES ('A',1), ('B',2), ('C',3);
INSERT INTO bar ( a, y ) VALUES ('A',4), ('C',5), ('D',6);

SELECT * FROM foo JOIN bar USING (a);
 a | x | y 
---+---+---
 A | 1 | 4
 C | 3 | 5
```

If foo and bar were different `ENUM` types as MySQL requires in it's `enum` "type", you'd have the same problem but PostgreSQL wouldn't allow the join at all, because they're different types. PostgreSQL also [won't allow one enum type to reference a different discrete enum type](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/207541/2639) type without manually providing a method to go from one enum to another.